# How to create and deploy IOS App from windows OS

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework

I'm creating a mobile application. The requirement is that the mobile application should be deployed in Android as well as iOS. I'm able to create the application and deploy it into Android using Ionic. But how do I do that for iOS. Is there a way we can use the Ionic in Windows OS and create app that is compatible with iOS.

Similar to Android Developer Options, is there any settings in IOS phones that will enable us to deploy the IOS app and test it.

Comment: No, proper iOS development requires owning a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Mac OS X on your Windows machine using VMWare player. try searching 'Mavericks Retail VMware Image' in google, you will get download links... Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need XCode to deploy any IOS application. To get XCode, you need a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The closeset thing you can do is using RemoteBuild, but you stil need a Mac.

After installing it, you can launch a build directly from Visual Studio.

For more information and a detailed guide, you can follow this link: https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild

Answer (score 0):

You need a macOS to test and deploy iOS application on App Store, You can't deploy application directly by using windows OS.

OR

If you want to deploy application using windows OS then you have to use any virtualization software like: [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org),
[vMware](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads/#all_products) and install macOs.